# Distribute Apps under Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

Is there any possibility to distribute Apps unter Mountain Lion?

If I use the xCode 4.5 Preview, I can't submit an App.
But 4.3 is not working under Mountain Lion.

What should I do?

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Oskar - Apple explicitly states they will not accept applications with this build. Why do you want to get around it? I have both versions of XCode on my system so I can continue to develop and submit using the approved version and use 4.5R3 to test and make sure I'm ready for the future. I'm not trying to be rude, but when you download you are being presented with an accurate consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode 4.4 from the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) or from the [Mac Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) on Apple's website.